# Tail a log file as subprocess in Python [Windows box]

Tags: python, windows, powershell, logging, cmd

I have a subprocess in Python that I kick off that produces a log file. I need another subprocess to tail this log file as it is being generated and obtain the results at the end of my first subprocess (the thing that generates the log file).

This needs to be achieved on Windows boxes so I cannot use tail. I have looked into `Get-Contents` but am not entirely sure whether I can make `Get-Contents` persist and return only when my first subprocess (the log generator) finishes execution.

How would I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but i think you can use `tail -f filename` even with a log file inside a windows batch